# Clean way percentage from string

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I clean away 29% from the string below using Javascript?

```
This is a long string which is 29% of the others.
```

I need some kind of way to remove all percentage so the code must work with this string too:

```
This is a long string which is 22% of the others.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The regular expression `\d+%` matches one or more digits followed by a `%`.  That is then followed by an optional space so you don't end up with two spaces in a row.

```
var s = "This is a long string which is 29% of the others.";
s = s.replace(/\d+% ?/g, "");
console.log(s);
// This is a long string which is of the others.
```

Without the optional space at the end of the expression, you end up with

```
    // This is a long string which is  of the others.
    //-------------------------------^^
```

Answer (score 6):

This ought to do the job!

```
var s = 'This is a long string which is 29% of the others.';
s = s.replace(/[0-9]+%\s?/g, '');
alert(s);
```

I used so called *Regular Expressions* to do this. If you want more information about the solution, [I'd recommend this website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)!

Comment: Close! But it only removes the % sign. I need to remove the digits too. So from the string above I need to remove 29 too.

Comment: @Jonathan: If you need to support decimals (e.g., "Blah blah 22.5% blah blah"), the regex is `/\d+(?:\.\d+)?%/g`, I believe.

Comment: @Jonathan: I think you must have mis-copied Zanathiel's answer, works for me (as does my regex for decimals, which will also happily accommodate integers): http://jsbin.com/inarux Note Michael's point about the space after, though.

Comment: Looks good! and works fine but instead of the 29% I now get white space. How can I remove this too?

Comment: @JonathanClark: See Michael's answer below, he has it optionally remove whitespace at the end. But note that if you have, say "And then we discounted it 29%." you'll still get a space between "it" and the ".". Avoiding it is *much* more complicated. :-) But I took it as a challenge; see my answer for how.

Comment: `/(?:\d*\.)*\d+%/` will cover values like .25% should they arise.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Good point, but I wouldn't do it that way, it allows .25.25.25.25.25%. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Ugh, you're right. More like `/\s(?:\d*\.)?\d+%/` or maybe a `\b` instead of the `\s`, but definitely needed the `?` instead of the `*`.

Answer (score 2):

You've mentioned handling whitespace. Here's a solution that handles whitespace and potential decimal points within the percentage:

```
s = s.replace(/( ?)\d+(?:\.\d+)?%( ?)/g, function(m, c0, c1) {
  if (c0 === " " && c1 === " ") {
    return " ";
  }
  return "";
});
```

Live demo: [Run](http://jsbin.com/awocak) | [Edit](http://jsbin.com/awocak/edit)

Here's how that works:

- The initial `( ?)` is a capture group that captures a space in front of the digits if there is one. If there isn't one, it'll get nothing, because the `?` makes the space optional.
- The `\d+` matches leading digits.
- The `(?:\.\d+)` matches an *optional* decimal point followed by more digits. (It's *not* a capture group, the `(?:xxx)` format is for grouping without capturing; the `?` after it is to make the entire thing optional.)
- The `%` matches a `%`, of course.
- The `( ?)` at the end captures a space following the `%`, if there is one; again it's optional.
- `String#replace` allows you to give a function that will get called rather than just a simple replacement string.
- The function receives the full match as the first argument, then the capture groups as the remaining arguments. If both capture groups have spaces in them, there were spaces on both sides of the percentage and so we return a single space (to avoid jamming the words before and after the percentage together). Otherwise, there was no space either before or after the percentage, so we return nothing at all so we eat the space that was there.

If you also want to handle things like `.25%`, the regex changes a bit:

```
/( ?)(?:(?:\d+\.\d+)|(?:\.\d+)|(?:\d+))%( ?)/g
```

Live demo: [Run](http://jsbin.com/awocak/4) | [Edit](http://jsbin.com/awocak/4/edit)

Breakdown:

- `( ?)` - Same as before.
- `(?:...|...|...)` - An *alternation*, it will match one of the alternatives given. The alternatives we give it are:

  - `(?:\d+\.\d+)` - One or more digits followed by a decimal point followed by one or more digits.
  - `(?:\.\d+)` - A leading decimal point followed by one or more digits
  - `(?:\d+)` - Just a series of digits
- `%` - Match the `%`
- `( ?)` - Same as before

All the rest is the same.

Comment: What are you doing way down here? I didn't even see that you had an answer! ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do

```
This is a long string which is <span id="pct">29%</span> of the others.
```

And then when you want this to change in some javascript just use:

```
var i = 22; //change this to what you want :)
document.getElementById("pct").innerHTML = i +"%";
```

Comment: Granted it's probable, but the OP isn't *necessarily* doing this on a web browser. The days when JavaScript was confined to web browsers are well and truly gone (if they ever really existed).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: More likely, the OP is doing this in a browser, but just for reasons unrelated to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to replace digits followed by "%"

```
var str = "This is a long string which is 29% of the others.";

var withoutPercentage = str.replace(/(\d+%)/, "");
```

Comment: No need for the capture group.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably regular exressions. This expression will get you the percentage: `\d+%`.

So something like this should do the trick:

```
var s='This is a long string which is 22% of the others.';
s= s.replace(/\d+%/g, 'REPLACE');
alert(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

`var numStr = "100%";
var num1 =  2;

numStr = numStr.replace("%","")

var calculateValue = num1*numStr;
//output: calculateValue : 200 `

```
In Javascript Strings are immutable. Hence, we need to add methods which are available to change the characters or replace the characters in the strings.
Also, using string methods will not change the existing String but will return the newly created character string. 
For example in above code numStr is an String integer and I would like to replace the "%" character from the string with ""(empty string).
So, we can make use of String.replace("value tobe replaced", "new value");
calculateValue is an variable used to store the calculated value for num and numStr and perform the calculation.
```

Comment: Please add an explanation

Comment: In Javascript Strings are immutable. Hence, we need to add methods which are available to change the characters or replace the characters in the strings.